# JQuery - Animation Being Called Unwillingly

Tags: jquery

```
var open = false;

$(".fiveGuysStyle").click(function() {
    if(open == false) {
        $("#top").removeClass("BrotateTop").addClass("rotateTop");
        $("#mid").css("visibility", "hidden");
        $("#btm").removeClass("BrotateBtm").addClass("rotateBtm");

        open = true;
    }
    if(open == true) {
        $("#top").removeClass("rotateTop").addClass("BrotateTop");
        $("#mid").css("visibility", "visible");
        $("#btm").removeClass("rotateBtm").addClass("BrotateBtm");

        open = false;
    }
});
```

---

The problem that is occurring is when the btn is being clicked the first if statement is being called but then a split second after the second if statement is being called.

Comment: Check my answer @Seth J. Freeman.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its executing because the first `if` condition is making `open` variable value `true`.
You should `if` , `else`

```
var open = false;

$(".fiveGuysStyle").click(function() {
    if(open == false) {
        $("#top").removeClass("BrotateTop").addClass("rotateTop");
        $("#mid").css("visibility", "hidden");
        $("#btm").removeClass("BrotateBtm").addClass("rotateBtm");

        open = true;
    }
    else {
        $("#top").removeClass("rotateTop").addClass("BrotateTop");
        $("#mid").css("visibility", "visible");
        $("#btm").removeClass("rotateBtm").addClass("BrotateBtm");

        open = false;
    }
});
```

Comment: Sorry, I got caught up in other things.